# Is it safe to define application model in Ember.js and javascript generally speaking?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, client-side

I'm used to ASP.NET MVC, Razor, server-side programming and I'm currently building a Presentation Layer using Ember.js. All the underlying layers are "safe" on a ASP.NET server and I'm exposing a REST API using Web API.  However I'm seriously wondering if using a javascript client-side framework is a good idea as far as Intellectual Property is concerned.

What bothers me the most is that I am required to write my data model in Ember.js to use Ember-Data conveniently. Isn't it giving my app for free to people ? Even if my business code is on the server, if people have access to my model isn't it already too much ?
 One idea I had was to reduce the properties I replicate on the client-side to the minimum necessary, but I don't know if it will have drawbacks on the long run.

So basically here are my two questions : What is the best way to minimize the risk induced by the fact of putting the model on the client-side, and do you agree that it's really a risk ? Why do you use these frameworks knowing this fact ?

Having developed several front-end using ASP.NET MVC, I can tell that using Web API + Ember.js is a much more straightforward, convenient and productive way of doing things. I find that I develop the user interface much more quickly. However, I wonderer if it is an intelligent and acceptable solution if we consider Intellectual Property.

PS: When I say risk, I'm mostly thinking of people who would like 'steal' the app. I feel that if they know the model, they can "easily" guess the architecture and have an idea of how I'm doing stuff. Security matters are okay.

Comment: You have no problems any different than one million other people writing webapps. There is not a huge amount an evil person can do with a big steaming pile of obfuscated JS and some network traces. If you're talking real secret confidential game-changing IP, then sure, structure your app to conceal more of that on the server. My guess is that your "architecture", with all due respect, does not fall into that category.

Comment: people who steal don't buy software, so you are unlikely to lose any money. used with a backend, ember and ilk are supposed to be offering a slice of the model, a view model. rather than put that view model in html during page shipping, it puts it in JSON after shipping the page, but the data should be the same either way.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, the perspective you provide is indeed very useful. Thank you for taking the time to write them. Building on your answers, I also realized that since the purpose of the front-end models is to focus on data that will be displayed to the user, I'm not giving away more IP by writing JS models than what I give away by presenting the data to the user. I just need to be careful with separation of concerns and only put display logic and no business logic on the client side. The answer to my question is a combination of our 3 comments !